# What does this logic do in JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning react and came across a tutorial where a delete button is added in the JSX and a function has been defined to  execute the event. However, I am confused what does the code below do.

```
const deleteList=this.state.list.filter(item=>item.objectID!==id);
```

In particular I am confused what does the below logic mean:

```
(item=>item.objectID!==id);
```

Comment: `filter` filters elements of array which doesn't fit with the condition. and the condition is that it's looking for a specific id.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why this wasn't understandable via just running some code and reading some docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.state.list.filter(item=>item.objectID!==id);
```

This part loops over all items in `list`, and returns a new array containing only items that match the condition `item.objectID!==id`
This is a common syntax to delete one element of a list.

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of `filter` method.

Comment: How does that happen? I mean when is id not equal to objectID?

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to

```
function(item) {
   return item.objectID!==id
}
```

Basically filter out all elements where id is not equal to item.objectID

Comment: How does that happen? I mean when is id not equal to objectID?

Comment: Basically your data is rendered from the array list so when you click on delete button you want to remove that element from the array list.So you pass the id of the element on which you initiated delete.So, the tasks is to filter all the elements except the one on which you clicked delete.

Answer (score 1):

For Better understanding I am explaining it with an example.
see the below code:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [
        { id: '1', age: 42 },
        { id: '2', age: 33 },
        { id: '3', age: 68 },
      ],
    };
  }

  onRemoveItem = id => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const list = state.list.filter(item => item.objectID !== id);

      return {
        list,
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map(item => (
            <li key={item.objectID}>
              The person is {item.age} years old.
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => this.onRemoveItem(item.objectID)}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Above code we have React state array of objects (i.e. objectid and age). 
while defining onRemoveItem methods **id** is the parameter.

when onRemoveItem methods is called on the button click event an item.objectID is passed as parameter.

```
onRemoveItem = id => {
        this.setState(state => {
          const list = state.list.filter(item => item.objectID !== id);
```

Here we filter the item from the React state array whose objectid is id and id is nothing but the objectid which is passed as a parameter on the **onRemoveItem** method calling.